# How to total a row based on another row datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am new here, but I want to ask something. I have

[image]

And I want to fill my `dataGridTwo` automatic when a row added in `dataGridOne`. In `dataGridTwo` Quantity cell is summing the `dataGridOne` Quantity cell with a same `dataGridOne` Shipping Container cell.

[image]

Comment: Are the Grids on the same form or different forms?

Comment: The Grids are in the same form.

Comment: If I add a row to `dataGridOne` such as `... | ... | 1234 | Mega Bag Glass | 250`, how should `dataGridTwo` be updated? **1)** `Mega Bag Glass | ... | 3`; or **2)** `Mega Bag Glass | ... | 900`.  Your screenshots imply option 1 but your verbage implies option 2.

Comment: @OhBeWise if you add a row to `dataGridOne` like that, `dataGridTwo` updates like your first option **1)**  `Mega Bag Glass | ... | 3`. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to handle the `CellEndEdit` event for cells in your "Shipping Container" column:

```
dataGridOne.CellEndEdit += DataGridOne_CellEndEdit;
```

The idea is whenever a cell in the "Shipping Container" column has changed, you will iterate through all rows counting the number of occurrences per container.  Then you'll update `dataGridTwo` with those counts; adding any missing containers as needed.

Not to take away all the fun, the code / algorithm:

```
private void DataGridOne_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // ColumnName = the Name of the Shipping Container Column
    if (dataGridOne.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == dataGridOne.Columns["ColumnName"])
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> sums = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // For each row that's not the new row in dataGridOne
        //     key = the value in cell["ColumnName"] of the row (i.e. "Mega Bags")
        //     if sums contains the key, increment sums value
        //     else sums value is 1

        // For each row that's not the new row in dataGridTwo
        //     key = the value in cell["ColumnName"] of the row (i.e. "Mega Bags")
        //     if sums contains the key, set the cell value to sums value
        //     else set the cell value to 0
        //     remove the key from sums

        // For each remaining KeyValuePair in sums
        //     add a new row to dataGridTwo using (key, CRIS ID, value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void cellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Only handles cases where the cell contains a TextBox
        var editedTextbox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;

        if (editedTextbox != null)
          {                
             //your logic of quntity
             grid2.rows.add();
             grid2.rows[grdi.rowcount-1].cell["Cell Name"].value=qty;
          }

    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but, my cell not contains a Textbox.

Comment: it will treat cell by default as textbox